#  How can I read a key value of Registry and print it to the screen with the MessageBox()

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to C++ and to WinCe developing.

I want to read a string from the registry and display with the `MessageBox()`. I have tried the following.

```
HKEY key;
if (::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers\\SiRFStar3HW"), 0, KEY_READ, &key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,L"Can't open the registry!",L"Error",MB_OK);
}
char value[5];
DWORD value_length=5;
DWORD type=REG_SZ;
RegQueryValueEx(key,(LPCTSTR)"Baud", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
wchar_t buffer[5];
_stprintf(buffer, _T("%i"), value);

::MessageBox(NULL,buffer,L"Value:",MB_OK);

::RegCloseKey(key);
```

So I know somethings wrong in here, but how can I solve?

Comment: Maybe you should start with understanding the difference between [ANSI and Unicode strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Keep in mind that Windows CE only supports the Unicode versions of most of the API functions to reduce code size.  While you're at it, also read through [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode And Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Lots of errors here. Registry code is wrong. Why are you reading into char array? You try to convert value to string with %i but pass a pointer to char array. And then you declare array of length 5 but want it to hold 6 characters. Back to basics first. Try to make this code work with the registry code removed. Then try to work out how to read registry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you're right. There are a lot of other discrepancies than what I'll get in an answer.

Comment: Im newbie I know. I just read an ebook about this, I never learn in school. The registry reading is from an example from here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/171917-how-to-setread-registry-key-in-c/ I now want learn myself, and the tutorials from the net...

Comment: So how looking a working code?

Comment: That example code is no good. All your strings are Unicode strings because CE doesn't do ANSI. Stop using `char`. You seem to be using a mix of macros, both `TEXT()` and `_T()`. Both seem pointless since you don't need to be able to compile for either ANSI or Unicode. I'd use `L"blah"` for my literals. But what is your question really about. Do you just want to know how to read a string from the registry?

Comment: Other erros: when you can't open the key, you give a messagebox, but then continue on and try using and invalid key to query a value.  You can't just cast an ASCII value to Unicode.  Quit using a mix of macros (I see `L`, `TEXT` and `_T` all in this short, poor code).  Pick one set (probably TCHARs for WinCE) and stick with that set.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes my really question example this. How can I read a key value of Registry and print it to the screen with the MessageBox()

Comment: @ctacke Yes, really! But its only a fastly maked example...

Comment: @ctacke Why use `TCHAR` for CE?! It doesn't do ANSI. I wouldn't use `TCHAR` on Windows nowadays.

Comment: Almost all Windows CE code is already written using the TCHAR macros.  The samples, the platform.  While CE have never done ANSI, it makes your code portable off of WinCE if you ever need it elsewhere and if I've learned anything in my years of development, it's that what you think you'll never do today is typically what you end up doing a year from now.

Comment: @ctacke You need to look at the history. When the sample code was written, Win 95/98 was prevalent. That platform did not have the Unicode APIs. But today, most people can simply ignore 95/98. And so can ignore ANSI APIs.

Comment: We'll just agree to differ.  I'm just looking at Windows CE.  The platform code that ships *today* includes almost exclusively TCHAR calls.  Nearly all CE samples use TCHAR macros.  When a new person starts working with CE, they're going to see TCHAR macros everywhere.  When I see non-TCHAR code in CE, it sends up a red flag immediately.  Now it might be perfectly valid code, but the red flag made me slow down and analyze it more closely, costing me time I should have been doing something else.  There's a lot to be said for continuity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Navigating the Win32 API can be a tricky business. The registry APIs are some of the more complicated. Here's a short program to demonstrate how to read a registry string.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

wstring ReadRegValue(HKEY root, wstring key, wstring name)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(root, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw "Could not open registry key";

    DWORD type;
    DWORD cbData;
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    if (type != REG_SZ)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Incorrect registry value type";
    }

    wstring value(cbData/sizeof(wchar_t), L'\0');
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value[0]), &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    size_t firstNull = value.find_first_of(L'\0');
    if (firstNull != string::npos)
        value.resize(firstNull);

    return value;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wcout << ReadRegValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", L"CommonFilesDir");
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I don't have CE so this is a plain Win32 app, compiled for Unicode. I took that route because CE doesn't do ANSI characters.
2. I've taken advantage of a number of C++ features. Most significantly `std::wstring`. This makes string handling a cinch.
3. I've used exceptions for error handling. You could replace that with some other mechanism, but it served my purpose of keeping the error handling issues in the background.
4. Using exceptions makes closing the registry key slightly messy. A better solution would be to use an RAII class to wrap up the lifetime of the registry key. I've omitted that for simplicity, but in production code you would want to take that extra step.
5. Usually, `RegQueryValueEx` returns `REG_SZ` data that is null-terminated. This code deals with that by truncating beyond the first null character. In case the value returned is not null-terminated, that truncation won't happen, but the value will still be fine.
6. I've just printed to my console, but it would be trivial for you to call `MessageBox`. Like this: `MessageBox(0, value.c_str(), L"Caption", MB_OK)`

Comment: Thanks but I found a lot of tutorials for Win32! But the most functions are not working on WinCE.

Comment: Er, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: Example on your code you use iostream. For WinCe is not available.

Comment: Then take out iostream. That's just for console output.

Comment: wcout' : undeclared identifier

Comment: binary '<<' : no global operator defined which takes type 'class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,clas
s std::allocator<unsigned short> >' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: well of course not. That's from iostream. Replace it with your preferred output mechanism. If the function I wrote compiles on ce then you are golden. Really, you should spend a bit of time with a good book and get on top of the basics. Don run before you can walk.

Comment: There is a typo between "hkey" and "hKey" FYI.

Comment: I am using the same libraries as you but am getting the following errors

Comment: Thx for the code. I am using the same libraries as you but am getting the following errors, on "key.c_str()" i get type const wchar_t* incompatible with parameter of type lpcstr. also, error on "name.c_str()" same error as key. (sorry for the double post, i ran out of edit time)

Comment: Using your function, all I get is "硅浡汰⹥獶潨瑳攮數" - You need to use the "W" functions, i.e. `RegQueryValueExW`

Comment: @bytecode see note 1 where I state that the code must be compiled with Unicode defines

Comment: Invallid Arguments: WINADVAPI LONG WINAPI RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY);

Comment: You are passing wide text to the ANSI function

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete source code to read a key value of Registry and print it to the screen:

```
//Create C++ Win32 Project in Visual Studio
//Project -> "project" Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Show Includes : YES(/ showIncludes)
//Project -> "project" Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Use of MFC : Use MFC in a shared DLL
#include <iostream>
#include <afx.h>
using namespace std;

int ReadRegistryKeyAttributes(CString ConstantKeyPath)
{
    //Here ConstantKeyPath is considered as Registry Key Path to Read
    HKEY MyRegistryKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, ConstantKeyPath, 0, KEY_READ, &MyRegistryKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "KeyOpen Failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
    DWORD cbData;
    unsigned long size = 1024;
    CString csVersionID;

    csVersionID = _T("VersionID"); //Here VersionID is considered as Name of the Key
    if (RegQueryValueEx(MyRegistryKey, csVersionID, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&cbData, &size) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(MyRegistryKey);
        cout << "VersionID Key Attribute Reading Failed" << endl;
        return -1; //Error
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "VersionID = " << cbData << endl; //Key value will be printed here.
    }
    return 1; //Success
}
int main()
{
    int iResult;
    CString KeyPath = _T("Software\\RCD_Technologies\\Rajib_Test");
    iResult = ReadRegistryKeyAttributes(KeyPath);
    if (iResult < 0)
    {
        cout << "ReadRegistryKeyAttributes operation Failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "<--- ReadRegistryKeyAttribute Operation Successfull -->" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this example will be helpful who are seeking this problem.

Comment: Complete example of  Creation, Update, Read and Delete operation for Windows registry key will be found in this link: http://rajib.me/?p=93

Answer (score 1):

This is untested (my device doesn't have your key/value), but compiles for CE and gives you the gist of how you do what you're after:
    #include

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HKEY key;

    if(!RegOpenKeyEx(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
        _T("System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers\\SiRFStar3HW"), 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        &key))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to open key"), _T("Error"), 0);
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD length;

    // get the size - it's going to be 4 for a DWORD, but this shows how to deal with REG_SZ, etc
    if(!RegQueryValueEx(
        key, 
        _T("Baud"), 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        &length))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get buffer size"), _T("Error"), 0);
        goto exit;
    }

    // allocate - again, if we know it's a DWORD, this could be simplified
    BYTE *buffer = (BYTE*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, length);

    // query
    if(!RegQueryValueEx(
        key, 
        _T("Baud"), 
        NULL, NULL, 
        buffer, 
        &length))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get value data"), _T("Error"), 0);
        goto exit;
    }

    // assuming "baud" is a DWORD, not a string
    DWORD baud = *(DWORD*)buffer;

    // build an output
    TCHAR message[MAX_PATH];
    _stprintf(message, _T("The baud value is %i"), baud);
    MessageBox(NULL, message, _T("Success"), 0);

    exit:
    RegCloseKey(key);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When using a char array you will need to set not the buffer but the pointer to the buffer, like this:

```
MessageBox(0,&buffer,"Value:",MB_OK);
```

Comment: I have error: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'unsigned short (*)[5]' to 'const unsigned short *'

Comment: No, that's not it. Arrays decay to pointers to the first element.

Answer (score -1):

just use RegQueryValueEx and put it in buf