# Getting REG_DWORD from windows registry as a wstring

Tags: c++, window, registry, dword

I am working on a test which should check the registry value. My goal is to take 3 windows registry variables. I am using the modified solution from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675705/how-can-i-read-a-key-value-of-registry-and-print-it-to-the-screen-with-the-mess). The issue is that when I try to get the value which is REG_DWORD it just prints empty brackets. When I try to use it on REG_SZ it works perfectly fine. For now I use this code:

```
wstring UpgradeAutocompleteBeCopyFilesUt::ReadRegValue(HKEY root, wstring key, wstring name)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(root, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw "Could not open registry key";

    DWORD type;
    DWORD cbData;
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    if (type != REG_SZ && type != REG_DWORD)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Incorrect registry value type";
    }

    wstring value(cbData / sizeof(wchar_t), L'\0');
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value[0]), &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    
    size_t firstNull = value.find_first_of(L'\0');
    
    if (firstNull != string::npos)
        value.resize(firstNull);

    return value;
}
```

and this is how I print the variables:

```
std::wcout << L"first: " << regfirst << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"second: " << regsecond << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"third: " << regthird << std::endl;
```

Third one is REG_DWORD. First two are REG_SZ.

Is there any possible way to get the wstring out of the third variable?
I checked registry there should be a value of "1".

Comment: `REG_DWORD` is binary data and needs to be read into a `DWORD` not a string buffer. `REG_SZ` is string data and may or may not be zero-terminated. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types   _"...If data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ, or REG_EXPAND_SZ type, the string may not have been stored with the proper terminating null characters...."_

Comment: ok makes sense. So what do you propose? How should I edit the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (type != REG_SZ && type != REG_DWORD) ...
```

You just have to treat `REG_SZ` and `REG_DWORD` differently.

Also add an extra +1 for the null terminator to be safe.

```
wstring ReadRegValue(HKEY root, wstring key, wstring name)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(root, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw "Could not open registry key";
    DWORD type;
    DWORD cbData;
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, 
            name.c_str(), NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    std::wstring value;
    if (type == REG_SZ)
    {
        value.resize(1 + (cbData / sizeof(wchar_t)), L'\0');
        if (0 == RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL,
            reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(value.data()), &cbData))
        { //okay 
        }
    }
    else if (type == REG_DWORD)
    {
        DWORD dword;
        if (0 == RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, &type,
            reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&dword), &cbData))
            value = std::to_wstring(dword);
    }
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return value;
}
```